# Workaround for URL Hack to prepopulate fields on standard page layout

Tags: custom-button, urlhacking, url, list-button

[**As URL Hack is not Officially Supported by Salesforce**](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000176169&language=en_US).

**Is there a workaround for this without overriding standard pages with visualforce page or Ajax ToolKit?**

For example, if you click on the "New Opportunity" button in the Opportunity related list on the Account page, it will be directed to the new "Oppurtunity Edit" page.Here you will see Account getting prepopulated on Opportunity and I want something like this without any URL Hack

Below is the Knowledge Article from Salesforce about URL Hack

> **[Knowledge Article Number: 000176169](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000176169&language=en_US)**
>
> Description I would like to be able to use the query string parameter
>   save=1 to have a custom button/link that automatically saves a case in
>   one click by using this URL:
>
> /{!CaseId}/s?save=1&cas7=Closed
>
> and I have seen in a developer forum
>   (http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/General-Development/quot-save-1-quot-attribute-no-longer-working/td-p/257227/highlight/true)
>   that Salesforce can enable "Autosave by URL" to allow this. Can this
>   be enabled in my org?
>
> Resolution NOTE: This is considered a URL hack and it is not supported
>   by Salesforce. Using undocumented query strings is absolutely
>   discouraged as Salesforce can change them at any time without notice.
>   Instead this requirement can be implemented by using the Force.com
>   AJAX toolkit or a Visualforce page with a custom controller.
>
> Salesforce has implemented several features to prevent Cross-Site
>   Request Forgery (CSRF). As an example when a browser makes a request a
>   one-time token is attached to prevent CSRF attacks, however this also
>   prevents the use of the mentioned URL as clicking on it would generate
>   a GET request without the CSRF token.
>
> Salesforce Support can disable the validation of the token on GET
>   requests, but this opens up the Salesforce application to CSRF
>   attacks. We strongly recommend that this feature remain enabled.
>   Customers can request this feature to be disabled though by raising a
>   case that contains the following statement/request:
>
> "Please disable the validation of the CSRF token on GET requests. I
>   acknowledge I understand that my organisation may be potentially
>   exposed to CSRF attacks, and I will continue without the feature at my
>   own risk."

Here are some useful links on URL Hack

http://andyinthecloud.com/2014/01/05/querying-custom-object-and-field-ids-via-tooling-api/

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000gM7mAAE

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: @AdrianLarson What is the workaround for this without overriding standard pages with visualforce page or Ajax ToolKit

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer to your question is **maybe**. Up until a couple years ago, asking support to disable validation of CSRF token on GET requests did the trick for allowing save=1 as a parameter in URL hacks. It's no longer possible.

If you don't need to automatically save, then you can still do URL hacks. Is there a particular use case you're trying to solve for?

I guess you should also check out Publisher Actions and the Process Builder. Those two functions solve many of the requirements previously only supported by APEX/Visualforce or URL hacks.